# Сохранения действия функции после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая меняет изображение по нажатию на определенную ссылку. (Если посмотреть код можно понять что и зачем). Так вот мне нужно чтобы действие функции сохранялось после обновления страницы.

P. S. Огромные ссылки нужны чтобы изображения были:)

```js
function l_image (a) {
         document.example_img.src=a
}
```

```html
<td width="35" height="35"><a href="profile.html"><img id="img" src="http://cs629428.vk.me/v629428612/1d5e8/S3_TyLWEBSY.jpg" width="35" height="35" name="example_img"/></a></td>
<td width="100" height="100">
       <div><a href="javascript:l_image ('agent_avatar1.png')"><img id="agent_avatar1" src="http://cs629428.vk.me/v629428612/1d5e8/S3_TyLWEBSY.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/></a><a href="javascript:l_image ('agent_avatar2.png')"><img id="agent_avatar2" src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629128/v629128393/283e7/fzgNFzYgoXw.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/></a><a href="javascript:l_image ('agent_avatar3.png')"><img id="agent_avatar3" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="100px" height="100px"/></a></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Сохраняйте результат изменения в get параметр ссылки. При загрузке страницы всегда проверяйте, если ли в гете что-либо и адаптируйте содержимое страницы

Comment: или в сессию, или в куки, или в локальное хранилище

Comment: Да, тоже вариант. Просто гет в ссылке точно поддерживают все браузеры)

Comment: это верно. но если пользователь будет сохранять в гет, то произойдет перезагрузка страницы, чтобы этого избежать можно использовать: **location.hash = 100**